# How to set memory region's protection in kernel mode under Windows 7

Tags: memory-management, windows-kernel

Essentially I am looking for a function that could do for kernel mode what `VirtualProtect` does for user mode.

I am allocating memory using a logic exemplified by the following simplified code.

```
    PMDL mdl = MmAllocatePagesForMdl    
    (
        LowAddress,
        HighAddress,
        SkipAddress,
        size
    );

    ULONG flags = NormalPagePriority | MdlMappingNoExecute | MdlMappingNoWrite;
    PVOID ptr = MmGetSystemAddressForMdlSafe
    (
        mdl, 
        flags
    );
```

The `MdlMappingNoExecute` and `MdlMappingNoWrite` flags will have effect only on Win8+. 

Moreover, using only `MmGetSystemAddressForMdlSafe` I cannot assign for example **`NoAccess`** protection for the memory region.

Are there any additional or alternative API-s I could use so that I can modify the page protection of the allocated memory? 

A hack would do too since currently this functionality would not be in use in production code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code I currently ended up using is below. 

All used APIs are official.

Here I create another *mdl* for *subrange* of the allocated memory and change protection of that subrange.

If You trip over memory protected with this method below then:

- at `IRQL < DISPATCH_LEVEL` You will get `PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA` fault *(Invalid system memory was referenced.  This cannot be protected by try-except,
  it must be protected by a Probe.  Typically the address is just plain bad or it
  is pointing at freed memory.)*
- at `IRQL == DISPATCH_LEVEL` You will get
  `DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL` fault *(An attempt was made to access a pageable (or completely invalid) address at an
  interrupt request level (IRQL) that is too high.  This is usually
  caused by drivers using improper addresses.)*

Note that changing the protection might fail if the *subrange* is part of *large page* allocation. Then the `status` will be likely `STATUS_NOT_SUPPORTED`. 

*Large page* allocations can happen if the *originally allocated* memory region's size and alignment (which depends on `SkipAddress` variable in the question) are suitable and some additional preconditions are fulfilled with which I am not familiar with (perhaps starting from certain OS version).

```
        PMDL guard_mdl = IoAllocateMdl
        (
            NULL, 
            PAGE_SIZE * guardPageCount, 
            FALSE,           
            FALSE,  
            NULL        
        );

        if (guard_mdl)
        {
            IoBuildPartialMdl
            (
                mdl,    
                guard_mdl,  
                (PVOID)(0),  // **offset** from the beginning of allocated memory ptr
                PAGE_SIZE * guardPageCount
            );

            status = MmProtectMdlSystemAddress
            (
                guard_mdl,
                PAGE_NOACCESS
            );
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
C:\Windows\System32>dumpbin /exports ntdll.dll | find "Protect"
        391  17E 0004C030 NtProtectVirtualMemory
       1077  42C 000CE8F0 RtlProtectHeap
       1638  65D 0004C030 ZwProtectVirtualMemory
```

I think you can call `Zw` functions from kernel mode, and the args are generally the same as for the corresponding `Nt` functions.  And while `ZwProtectVirtualMemory` is undocumented, there is a documented [ZwAllocateVirtualMemory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff566416%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) that accepts protection flags.

Another approach might be to allocate and protect virtual memory in user-mode, pass the buffer down to your driver, then create the corresponding MDL there.

Comment: Thanks. Do You happen do know, can these API-s be applied to non-paged and system (not process associated) memory too?

Comment: *The `ZwAllocateVirtualMemory` routine reserves, commits, or both, a region of pages within the user-mode virtual address space of a specified process* - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff566416%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
While Your answer is still useful, the question currently somewhat implicitly asks for a solution to nonpaged memory since `MmAllocatePagesForMdl` generates nonpaged memory allocation - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff554482(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: It would still be interesting to know whether the undocumented `ZwProtectVirtualMemory` API is capable of working on nonpaged memory and how it differs from `MmProtectMdlSystemAddress`? I think I understand that `NtProtectVirtualMemory` is for user-mode memory and will fail with arguments pointing to system memory range. 
The difference between `Zw` and `Mm` APIs is interesting since in the internet one can find various hacks to call `ZwProtectVirtualMemory` API. If not for certain advantages... then I assume these hacks would not have been made?